# Mat-table event on row Added

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I want to do an action when a new row is added in mat-table but I'm not able to know when it happens. There any emitter or another way? I've read all mat-table doc and search on Internet and I haven't found anything.

I want this:

`<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;" onAdd=(function())>`

To update my datasource I just put:
`this.datasource.data = newData`

Comment: How is the new table row added?

Comment: @Rob, I change the datasource because a can't know the new rows to add.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - do you mean you load new data using an http request?

Comment: @Rob y, I have a subscription that overrides the datasource. I need to know wich rows are new and what isn't.

Comment: Does every row have a unique ID of some type?

Comment: @Rob yes, each row has a primaryKey but I material doesn't provide a method to get a row by ID.

Comment: The way I see it you will have to track the data changes as part of the datasource update in the component.ts file. Before you overwrite the datasource iterate the new data and check to see if each ID in the new datasource exists in the old data source - if it doesn't you can then store it in an array and reference it from a function in your tr element e.g. [class.active]="isNewRow(row.ID)". If you need to perform more complex functions like your onAdd() function then do it in the component.ts file as you're finding the new rows

Comment: @Rob, I will try this, but I think that when a row updates more than 1 time, css animation will not run again. If I could have the reference of <tr> to work with it in .ts it would be fine. Any idea?

Comment: @Rob I've tried your solution, the problem is that I can't wait to compare new datasource with old datasource, I've tried to use promise to wait before to assign but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the code for your datasource update

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like the following (I used an existing model I had in my code "CaseDetailModel" as you've not provided any info about your data types):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CaseDetailModel } from '../../models/casedetailmodel';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stackoverflow',
  templateUrl: './stackoverflow.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stackoverflow.component.scss']
})

export class StackoverflowComponent implements OnInit {

  private currentCaseDetails: CaseDetailModel[] = [];
  private newCaseDetails: CaseDetailModel[] = [];

  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<CaseDetailModel>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<CaseDetailModel[]>('/some/data/').subscribe((caseDetails: CaseDetailModel[]) => {

      //This if statement will stop the initial list items all being classed as new - you may want to remove it
      if (this.currentCaseDetails.length) {
        //Get any items that do not currently exist in the table
        this.newCaseDetails = caseDetails.filter(cd => {
          return !this.currentCaseDetails.some(ccd => ccd.caseId === cd.caseId);
        });
      }

      this.newCaseDetails.forEach(ncd => {
        //Do something with each new item
      });

      this.currentCaseDetails = caseDetails;

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(caseDetails);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In neCaseDetails I only have the values not the row, so I need as you said before a another method to check if It's a new row. Then It's works propertly but I have another complications on my code.